# Calculating probability given joint probability density of a pair given by $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$

Tags: probability, statistics

This question was given to me as a review for an upcoming exam.

Calculate $P(Y \leq X^2)$ if the joint probability density of the pair $(X,Y)$ is given by $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=x^{-2}y^{-2}$ for $x,y\geq 1$.

What I've attempted thus far:

$P(Y \leq X^2) = \int \int_{y \leq 2x} x^{-2}y^{-2} dx dy$

= $\int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{x^2}x^{-2}y^{-2} dy dx$

= 0.6667

Are the bounds set up correctly? If not, how would I go about finding the correct bounds?

Comment: It should be $\int_{y=1}^\infty  \int_{x=\sqrt{y}}^\infty$, or equivalently, $\int_{x=1}^\infty  \int_{y=1}^{x^2}$.

Comment: dx dy? Shouldn't the inner bound be with respect to y if we are integrating dx dy

Comment: Never mind, I understand my error, I've updated the OP to reflect this change.